# Error in `filter()`: Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 0

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

I'm very new to R. I have this data frame named "log"

```
  a b c d e 
x 1 2 3 4 5 
y 1 na TRUE 2 five
z 1 2 3 TRUE FALSE
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five
```

I run this code that goes well.

```
> filter(log, grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", log$b)==TRUE)
```

Output
a    b     c     d    e
y    1   na  TRUE     2 five
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five

If I try to put this code in a function where object = log (my data frame) and column = a column of my data frame :

```
wrong <- function(object, column){
      filter(object, grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", object$column)==TRUE)
}
```

I get this error

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", object$column) == TRUE`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 0.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─global wrong(log, b)
  2. │ ├─dplyr::filter(...)
  3. │ └─dplyr:::filter.data.frame(object, grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", object$column) == TRUE)
  4. │   └─dplyr:::filter_rows(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
  5. │     └─dplyr:::filter_eval(dots, mask = mask, error_call = error_call)
  6. │       ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  7. │       └─mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
  8. ├─dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)
  9. │ └─rlang::abort(class = c(class, "dplyr:::internal_error"), dplyr_error_data = data)
 10. │   └─rlang:::signal_abort(cnd, .file)
 11. │     └─base::signalCondition(cnd)
 12. └─dplyr (local) `<fn>`(`<dpl:::__>`)
 13.   └─rlang::abort(bullets, call = error_call, parent = skip_internal_condition(e))
```

I don't understand what's wrong, why the first code works but the second dosen't work. I tried to modify my code but it didn't work.
Any help appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$column` will not work as `column` it will look for the literal `column` instead of the value.  Also, not clear if we are passing unquoted or quoted i.e. string column name in the function.  If we are passing unquoted, use `{{}}` operator.  Also, note that `grepl` returns a logical vector as output i.e. TRUE/FALSE, therefore, there is no need to do another comparison (`== TRUE`) on top of it

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(object, column){
       filter(object, grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", {{column}}))
 }
```

-testing

```
> f1(log, b)
     a    b     c     d    e
y    1   na  TRUE     2 five
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five
```

It may not work if we est as `f1(log, "b")`.  To make it more general, i.e. to pass either unquoted or quoted, convert to `sym`bol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
f2 <- function(object, column)
    {
    filter(object, grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", !! rlang::ensym(column)))
   }
```

-testing

```
> f2(log, b)
     a    b     c     d    e
y    1   na  TRUE     2 five
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five
> f2(log, "b")
     a    b     c     d    e
y    1   na  TRUE     2 five
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five
```

---

Another option is also to make use of `.data[[column]]` if we pass as string or if there are one or more columns, use `if_any/if_all` as well

```
f3 <- function(object, column){
      filter(object, if_any(all_of(column), ~ grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", .x)))
}
```

-testing

```
> f3(log, "b")
    a    b     c     d    e
y    1   na  TRUE     2 five
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE five
> f3(log,  c("b", "c", "e"))
     a    b     c     d     e
y    1   na  TRUE     2  five
z    1    2     3  TRUE FALSE
t TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  five
```

#### data

```
log <- structure(list(a = c("1", "1", "1", "TRUE"), b = c("2", "na", 
"2", "TRUE"), c = c("3", "TRUE", "3", "FALSE"), d = c("4", "2", 
"TRUE", "FALSE"), e = c("5", "five", "FALSE", "five")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("x", 
"y", "z", "t"))
```