# Problem with `filter()` within R function: "Input `..1` must be of size 262 or 1, not size 0"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset that includes all words produced by different speakers over different timepoints (AOPs). For each speaker at each timepoint, I want to create a list of all the known and unknown words.

I've created a function in R to do this. I run this function twice, one for 'actual' data, and once for 'target' data. The function and data structure are exactly the same, except that the word 'actual' is replaced with the word 'target':

```
 prepared_data_target <- lapply(AOP_list, FUN = function(element) {                                         
   data <- target_data %>% filter(data_type == "target" & Speaker == element$Speaker)   # select the speaker
   timepoint <- data %>% filter(AOP == element$AOP)  # select the timepoint                            
   timepoint <- timepoint$AOP # log the timepoint in its own df
   unknown <- data %>% filter(AOP > timepoint) # filter for all as-yet-unknown words                                  
   known <- data %>% filter(AOP <= timepoint)      # filter for all known words           
   output <- list(timepoint, known, unknown)
 })
```

The 'actual' code runs fine, but when I run the 'target' code afterwards I get the following error message:

```
 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
 i Input `..1` is `AOP > timepoint`.
 x Input `..1` must be of size 262 or 1, not size 0.
```

I've tried wrapping my filtered variables in `{{}}` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271244/error-in-filter-input-1-must-be-of-size-4-or-1-not-size-0), but that doesn't work.

[A sample of the data can be found here](https://github.com/cathelaing/PhonologicalNetworks/blob/main/target_data_subset.R).

[And the list here](https://github.com/cathelaing/PhonologicalNetworks/blob/main/AOP_list_subset.R).

Comment: You are comparing AOP with the whole array of element$AOP everytime, this cannot work. What are trying to achieve?

Comment: Still this cannot work because you are trying to compare each instance of AOP with the array element$AOP. This is causing your Error. Maybe you can provide some sample data and the expected output.